# having an issue with ios twitter app and attribution

Tags: ios, cocoa, twitter, sdk, twrequest

I have read all the posts I can find and seriously how to stop this "via iOS" tag and put my app name? I have all the links, nobody else has my name, what else do I need to do?  I am using TWRequest is that the problem?  Any info would be great thanks!

rc

Comment: What are you talking about? Is this a programming question?

Comment: Yes sorry if I didn't explain properly. When making an ios app that posts to twitter it's expected that it will give attribution when posting so "via appname" instead of "via ios". i see there are lots of problems with this and i'm looking for the solution because when it says "via ios" it doesn't do much to help me promote my app. thanks!